# Finding a particular kind of basis of subgroup of a lattice generated by non-negative part

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, lattices, modules, abelian-groups

For $\mathbf v=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)\in \mathbb Z^n$, let $\operatorname{supp}(\mathbf v):=\{j: v_j \ne 0\}$. For a subset $X$ of $\mathbb Z^n$, define $\operatorname{supp}(X):=\bigcup_{\mathbf v \in X} \operatorname{supp}(\mathbf v)  $.

Let $L$ be a lattice in $\mathbb Z^n$ i.e. $L$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb Z^n$.  Let $\mathbb N$ be the set of non-negative integers. Assume $L\cap \mathbb N^n \ne \{\mathbf 0\}$. Put $L_{\ge 0}$ to be the subgroup of $L$ generated by $L\cap \mathbb N^n$.

Then, must $L_{\ge 0}$ admit a $\mathbb Z$-module basis $\mathcal B$ such that $\mathcal B \subseteq L\cap \mathbb N^n$, and $ \operatorname{supp}(\mathbf u)= \operatorname{supp}(L\cap \mathbb N^n), \forall \mathbf u \in \mathcal B $  ?

Comment: A lattice in $\mathbf{Z}^n$ would rather be a *finite index* subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}^n$. However, the condition $L\cap\mathbf{N}^n\neq 0$ is automatic for a lattice when $n>0$, so you probably indeed mean an arbitrary subgroup. Also $L_{\ge 0}$ is quite a counter-intuitive notation. Actually, it seems that the question could be formulated with a subgroup $M$ such that $M$ is generated by $M\cap\mathbf{N}^n$, without further assumption (the case $M\cap\mathbf{N}^n$ being a trivial case). However, $n=2$, $M$ subgroup generated by $(1,0)$ makes a trivial counterexample.

Comment: @YCor: I am sorry, but I quite don't want the basis to have all non-zero components ... I'll edit my question ...

Comment: @YCor: I have updated my question now ... and yes, by Lattice I only mean a subgroup (not necessarily of finite index) such that it has a non-zero vector with all non-negative components ... I would be happy to incorporate if you have/happen to know a more intuitive or commonly used notation for the subgroup of $L$ generated by $L\cap \mathbb N^n$

Comment: If $L_{\ge 0}=\{0\}$, the basis is empty, so this is a tautological case. You can exclude it anyway even if it unnecessary. I already suggested a way to avoid introducing the notation, namely by assuming from the beginning that $L$ is generated by $L\cap\mathbf{N}^n$.

Comment: Your question has a positive answer. After removing irrelevant coordinates, the assumption is therefore that $L\cap\mathbf{N}_{>0}^n$ is nonempty. So it boils down to proving that for every nonempty open cone $C$ in $\mathbf{R}^d$, there is a basis of $\mathbf{Z}^d$ contained in $C$. This is very easy to prove.